# Selecting subclass based on user input?

Tags: java, class, if-statement, initialization

I am trying to select a specific subclass based on the user input, but I'm not quite sure how to do this. For example:

```
System.out.println("Select animal:\n1. Cat\n2. Dog");
int input = keyboard.nextInt();

if(input == 1){
     Cat newPet = new Cat();
}
else{
    Dog newPet = new Dog();
}
```

This is just a quick example I created just now, so excuse any syntax errors. I understand that once the if statement is over, the `newPet` object is out of scope so it can no longer be used afterwards. I also tried cases but this does not work, since I am declaring `newPet` twice, even though only one can be accessed in every run of the program.

Depending on the user input, multiple different factors further down in the program would be affected. I could always use an if statement in each of the different factors, but was wondering if theres a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an interface, Animal. 
Cat and Dog should implement Animal.
Your code can be changed to something like

```
System.out.println("Select animal:\n1. Cat\n2. Dog");
int input = keyboard.nextInt();
Animal pet=null;
if(input == 1){
     pet = new Cat();
}
else{
    pet = new Dog();
}
```

This should help maintaining a cleaner approach as well.

Comment: Also note that if `Cat` and `Dog` does not share a common superclass/interface you can always declare `pet` as an `Object` but creating a common interface is cleaner.

Comment: @Gaël : in this case it to call any method we will need to typecast it, this approach might work however it won't be cleaner.

Comment: I'd rather use an abstract class `Animal` in this scenario than an interface. :) But I know what you mean since it's probably the most common example for polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill Map with needed subclasses and use newInstance() method:

interface Animal 
{

}

class Cat implements Animal
{

}

class Dog implements Animal
{

}

```
    Map<Integer, Class> animals= new HashMap<Integer, Class>();
    animals.put(0, Cat.class);
    animals.put(1, Dog.class);

    System.out.println("Select animal:\n1. Cat\n2. Dog");
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();     
    Animal yourAnimal = (Animal) animals.get(input).newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

- **factories** which create pet instances (in Java 8: `Supplier<Pet>`)
- a **mapping** between input values and the factories
- a **strategy** what to return if no valid input is provided (could be a check which throws an exception if no factory is mapped for the input value, or a default factory which returns a default pet or null).

Code:

```
Map<Integer, Supplier<Pet>> factories = new HashMap<>();
factories.put(1, Cat::new);
factories.put(2, Dog::new);

Supplier<Pet> defaultPetSupplier = () -> null;
Function<Integer, Pet> f = i -> factories.getOrDefault(i, defaultPetSupplier).get();

System.out.println("Select animal:\n1. Cat\n2. Dog");
int input = keyboard.nextInt();

Pet pet = f.apply(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **avoid type casting**, then you have to do a little bit more work. But still you have to use polymorphism concept.
Create an interface named Pet and include all the methods contained by Cat and Dog classes in Pet interface as abstact methods.

```
class Cat {
    public void catMethod1() {
    }

    public void catMethod2() {
    }
}

class Dog {
    public void dogMethod() {
    }
}

interface Pet {
    public void catMethod1();

    public void catMethod2();

    public void dogMethod();
}

class HelperClass implements Pet {
    Cat cat;
    Dog dog;

    public HelperClass(int input) {
        if (input == 1) {
            cat = new Cat();
        } else {
            dog = new Dog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dogMethod() {

        if (dog == null) {
            return;
        }
        dog.dogMethod();
    }

    @Override
    public void catMethod1() {
        if (cat == null) {
            return;
        }
        cat.catMethod1();

    }

    @Override
    public void catMethod2() {
        if (cat == null) {
            return;
        }
        cat.catMethod2();

    }

}
```

Now you can access method without typecasting.

**Pet newpet =  new HelperClass(input);**

**newpet.catMethod2();**

Comment: with this approach, you do not have to modify your Dog and Cat class.